# undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contacts, spree

I'm using Spree, and setting up the spree_easy_contact extension.

When I send an email, it sends correctly, and saves it to the database correctly, but I'm redirected to an error screen :

```
NoMethodError in ContactsController#create

undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass
```

It doesn't give any hints as to where this might be erring. Does anyone know what this error is caused by?

Here is the only thing left in my log :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4980.8ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (5123.9ms)
```

This is from the Gem's contact_controller :

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact] || {})
  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.valid? &&  @contact.save
      ContactMailer.message_email(@contact).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => t("message_sended")) }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is in this line:

format.html { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => t("message_sended")) }

Can you increase logging to see where this error is happening?

Maybe you can set config.log_level = :debug to get more information.

Comment: It should be one of the symbols mentioned here: [Debugging Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)